# Running DB2 universal client on 64 bits windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, db2

We are trying to set up a development environment on a new machine.

Previously we have used this software on 32bit windows XP machines.

We tried installing the 32 bit version of DB2 universal client but the installation failed.

Is there a 64 bit version of DB2 universal client? Or is there a way to get the 32bit version to work on a 32 bit OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can download the 64-bit client for Windows from [this page](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg27007053&wv=1).

Support for Win7 64-bit is available in DB2 9.7 and DB2 9.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing it under XP mode (VirtualPC) for Windows 7 - http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx.